# Python: How to sum numbers from text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to sum numbers from text file in python? Let's say that we have some text document that have numbers like this:

```
320
5203
5246
```

And we want python open that file and sum those numbers to get to the result: 10769. How shall I do this?

Comment: How big of a file? Any other text in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is not too big, you can just read the file into an array, use a list comprehension to convert the lines into a list of integers and then compute the sum of that:

```
sum([int(s.strip()) for s in open('foo.txt').readlines()])
```

However, this reads the entire file into memory. If your file is large it would probably be less memory-intensive to accumulate the sum in an imperative manner:

```
result = 0
for s in open('foo.txt'): result += int(s.strip())
```

Or as a generator expression so that a list does not need to be stored in-memory

```
sum(int(s.strip()) for s in open('foo.txt'))
```

Comment: Interestingly, your concern about memory use could be addressed by simplifying your first suggestion:  `sum(int(s) for s in open('foo.txt'))`.  int will ignore trailing space for you, open files are iterable directly, and using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension will avoid another list.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: Ah, that's good to know! You should've made your comment a separate answer so that it can be accepted - it's certainly better than mine. I guess it doesn't matter, now that this question has been closed.