# I need help figuring out wha tI am doing wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on an assignment for school. I've emailed my professor and got very vague non helpful answers. Below is what I have to do

> Write and test a program to meet the following specifications:
>
> Write a function called fileToList(inFile) where inFile is a file that
>   has 7 lines with one number per line. The content of inFile is
>   transferred to a list called numbers. The function will return the
>   list called numbers that was created in the function (30 points).
>
> Write a function called sumList(nums) where nums is a list of numbers.
>   The function will return the sum of the numbers in the list (30
>   points).
>
> Write a function called main() that calls the functions
>   fileToList(inFile) and  sumList(nums) and prints the result of
>   sumList(nums) (30 points).
>
> Include a header at the top of the code with the following information
>   (5 points):
>
> ```
> # Name of programmer: you name goes here
> # Date: date program was written
> # Description: a description of what the program does.
> ```
>
> Use the file data.txt for your file that is read by the function
>   fileToList(inFile).

```
#SumList.py
# 02/26/2017
# This program will pull data from a file prints the data then sums the numeric data.



inFile = open("data.txt","r")
nums = []

def fileToList(inFile):
    numbers = []
for i in range(7):
    numbers.append(inFile.readline())
print('\n'.join(numbers))


def sumList(nums):
    file = open("data.txt","r")

    line = file.read()

    total = sum(file)

print(total)

def main():
    fileToList(inFile)
    sumList(nums)
main()
```

the data file

```
1245.67
1189.55
1098.72
1456.88
2109.34
1987.55
1872.36
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question, exactly? This isn't a tutoring service, but we can help you if you post a *specific question*. Also, the indentation here is definitely not correct. Is that how you've actually indented?

Comment: You may want to read [How to ask homework questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) before posting again.

Comment: I cant stand when people refer you to "How to ask questions..." because they know very well they did the same thing at the beginning of their programming journey and it helps nobody...

Comment: @pstatix It's a homework question. There is a fine line in "acceptable  formats" for those. (like *Never use code you don't understand*). And it is encouraged for everyone to go to the help center to see what is "on-topic" or not before posting any quesiton.

Comment: yea and have that stuff is full of over-done code. It's not helpful at all for entry level

Comment: @cricket_007 then at least point him the right direction. Don't blanket it to get kudos. You've still done nothing to encourage a solution.

Comment: @pstatix Excuse me? I did give an answer

Answer (score 0):

> The function **will return the list called numbers** that was created in the function

You need to return, not print.

```
def fileToList(inFile):
    numbers = [int(line) for line in inFile.readlines()]
    return numbers
```

> Write a function called sumList(nums) where nums is a list of numbers. The function **will return the sum of the numbers in the list**

Again, `return` is missing... And there is no file that should be `open()`-ed... Please read
[How to sum a list of numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472771/how-to-sum-a-list-of-numbers-in-python)

> Write a function called main() that calls the functions fileToList(inFile) and sumList(nums) and prints the result of sumList(nums)

You need to get the `return` values from the functions.

It is part of your assignment to figure that out, but here is a start

```
def main():
    with open("data.txt") as inFile:
        numbers = fileToList(inFile)
```

In much less code: [Python: How to sum numbers from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791256/python-how-to-sum-numbers-from-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

use `.strip()` to remove hidden characters/spaces around the `row`, and use `convert_2_decimal_float()` converting string to float value with 2 decimal precision.

```
def fileToList(inFile):
    numbers = []
    for row in inFile:
        float_value = convert_2_decimal_float(row.strip())
        print(float_value)
        numbers.append(float_value)
    print(','.join([str(n) for n in numbers]))
    return numbers


def sumList(nums):
    print(convert_2_decimal_float(sum(nums)))

def convert_2_decimal_float(v):
    return round(float(v), 2)

def main():
    inFile = open("sample.csv")
    nums = fileToList(inFile)
    sumList(nums)
    inFile.close()
main()
```

Open the file in method `main()`.
iterate `inFile` in `fileToList()`, add numbers in list `numbers` and returns the list, next step pass the returned list into `sumList()` and sum up all numbers by built-in method `sum()`, in the end close the opened file

Comment: @cricket_007 no it's not, `numbers` is a list of integers

Comment: Yeah, sorry, thought the print was the return

Comment: @cricket_007 no problem :)

Comment: @CharlesGoodling can you post a sample of your data file? Your data file might have non-numerical characters

Comment: @HaifengZhang oposted

Answer (score -1):

When reading the lines in your file you want to be converting the values to integers like so:
`numbers.append(int(inFile.readline()))`

You also want your fileToList function to actually return the list of numbers so you can use the list in main, not just print them therefore your fileToList function should look like:

```
def fileToList(inFile):
    numbers = []
    for i in range(7):
        numbers.append(float (inFile.readline()))
    return numbers
```

The sumList function can be a simple function that takes the list of numbers as a parameter and returns the sum:

```
def sumList(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

Therefore in main you can call fileToList and store the list of numbers returned in a variable:

```
def main():
    numbers = fileToList(inFile)
```

And then use the numbers as a parameter into the sumList function and print the result:

```
    print(sumList(numbers))
```

---

Program:

```
inFile = open("data.txt","r")

def fileToList(inFile):
    numbers = []
    for i in range(7):
        numbers.append(float(inFile.readline()))
    inFile.close()
    return numbers

def sumList(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)

def main():
    numbers = fileToList(inFile)
    print(sumList(numbers))

main()
```

Comment: If something is incorrect or not useful then please tell me but why the downvote otherwise?

Comment: it gives me a invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1245.67\n

Comment: Oh my bad, i wrongly assumed thst the data file consisted of integers so when I tried it with integer examples it worked, replace `int (inFile.readline ())` with `float (inFile.readline ())` I will edit my answer.